# Server status checker

Tags: ruby, networking, email, ssh, status-monitoring

I've created a program for work that checks the status of all our servers quickly. What we use to have to do is `ssh` into each server manually.

I'm looking for some critique on what I've created here. Any input on it would be greatly appreciated, such as better syntax I can use, better variables, easier ways to perform the rescue, etc. *I will be leaving out a couple of things for security purposes*.

```
#!/local/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh/gateway'
require 'work/mail/gem'

begin
  def scanning_all_ssh_servers(server_check, cmd)
    check = Net::SSH.start(server_check, @username, :password => @password)
    ping = check.exec!(cmd)
    case 
    when ping.include?("1 received, 0% packet loss")
      puts "server online: #{server_check}"
    when ping.include?("0 received, +1 errors")
       puts "SERVER OFFLINE: #{server_check}"
    when check.include?("Connection closed")
      puts "SERVER OFFLINE: #{server_check}"
    else
      raise "Error loading server: #{server_check}. Exiting.."
    end
  end

  @username = "username"
  @password = "password"


  ssh_server_list = %w(these are all the servers that we can ssh too)
  ssh_server_list.each do |server_check|
    cmd = "ping -c 1 #{server_check}"
    scanning_all_ssh_servers(server_check, cmd)
  end
rescue => e
  x = AD::Mail.new
  x.from        = "email@email.email"
  x.to          = "email@email.email"
  x.subject     = "Server Loading Error"
  x.body        = e.message
  x.send
end
```

Comment: [Follow-up question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/113676/9357)

Comment: @200_success thank you, didn't even think about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read my rewrite from the bottom up.  To appreciate the benefit, you notice how it clarifies the high level logic: your whole script is really only 4 lines long.

Some notes:

- Isolate your begin... rescue code.  This way all servers will be processed even if there's an error
- Break up each of your tasks into smaller, more focused methods (see below)
- Make sure your names are accurate: eg, `scanning_all_ssh_servers` really means "ping a particular server"
- Watch out for hidden entanglements in your code: your scan function takes a `cmd` argument, but this is a false abstraction, since the cody of the function assumes the cmd is a ping.  In this case, better to just leave the argument out.
- breaking out the mailer into its own method will make the high level logic clearer
- You can shorten up the ping function, while making it clearer imo, by losing the case statment (see below).  But if you don't like that, you should probably still use the regex version of case to avoid the repeated `ping.include?` calls.
- Another small point on naming: Avoid unnecessary adjectives.  In *this* context, all your "servers" are "ssh servers", so better to use names like `server_list` rather than `ssh_server_list`, which adds visual and auditory cruft without adding precision.

Rewrite:

```
def mail_error(e)
  x = AD::Mail.new
  x.from     = "email@email.email"
  x.to       = "email@email.email"
  x.subject  = "Server Loading Error"
  x.body     = e.message
  x.send
end

def ping_server(server)
  begin
    check = Net::SSH.start(server, @username, :password => @password)
    cmd = "ping -c 1 #{server}"
    check.exec!(cmd)
  rescue => e
    mail_error(e)
    :error
  end
end

def server_status(server)
  ping_result =  ping_server(server)

  online_text = /1 received, 0% packet loss/
  offline_text = Regexp.union('0 received, +1 errors', 'Connection closed')

  ping_result =~ online_text  ? :online  :
  ping_result =~ offline_text ? :offline : :error
end

def status_message(server, status)
  status == :online  ? "server online: #{server}"  :
  status == :offline ? "SERVER OFFLINE: #{server}" :
                       "Error loading server: #{server}. Exiting.."
end

@username = "username"
@password = "password"
server_list = %w(these are all the servers that we can ssh too)

server_list.each do |server|
  status = server_status(server)
  puts status_message(server,status)
end
```

### UPDATE: Additional Explanation

[`Regexp.union`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-c-union) allows you to easily create an "or"ed regexp from a number of strings.  So that when you match strings against the regexp you created, you'll get a match if *any* of the strings match.  It's equivalent to the regexp `|` "or" operator, but can often be a more readable way to create the regexp.

Re: your question about the `rescue` block, it depends, but I would think you only want the "server can't be reached" email when the "reach server" code fails.  That is, even though this code is simple, it's still possible you get some other error executing it, which should be reported as a script error (using a library like airbrake) rather than spawning a "server can't be reached" email.  Again, just separating you concerns.

Re: the distinction between ssh and rdp servers, that makes sense.

Comment: It looks very good, and reads very well also, I do have a couple questions though. What does `Regexp.union( )` do? Also, wouldn't it be safer to wrap the "main" function in the rescue, instead of the commands? One more thing is, I made the names `ssh_server_list`, etc.. Because we have a few servers here at work that can only be pinged, so I'm planning on implementing them into this program some how as an `rdp_server_list`:) that's for another time though. All together great rewrite!

Comment: Thanks.  I answered your followup questions in an update.

Answer (score 0):

### Loop logic

The script stops checking as soon as it encounters the first exception.  You probably intend to check every server in the list.

### Probe

The check that you are performing is to have every server ping itself.  Since we have already ascertained that we are able to SSH to the server, it would be extremely unlikely that the server would not be able to ping itself, unless you had a local firewall rule to discard ICMP echo requests.  The ping is therefore superfluous.  Any command would do.

### Standard tools

Consider using a standard server monitoring tool like Nagios instead of inventing your own custom script.  When you use standard tools, other sysadmins don't have to figure out how to maintain your code.

Comment: The reason I'm having it ping itself is because we've encountered a problem recently, that our admin is trying to solve, where we can SSH to the server yet it won't ping. Just covering all my bases