# Are your servers down...?

Tags: ruby, networking, email, ssh, status-monitoring

If you came here because of the title, chances are your server isn't down. But if by some miraculous reason it is:

A while ago, I posted a [program](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/113521/server-status-checker/113567?noredirect=1#comment210416_113567) that would ssh and ping all the servers at work. I got some very good feedback and went ahead and rolled with it.

Here's what I came up with:

- It now is much more readable, in my opinion
- Pings the servers after SSHing into them
- Then if it finds one of the servers to be offline, or errors out connecting, writes data to a `.txt` file containing the server name, and the user who deployed the program.

I of course will be leaving some information off due to security.

**Source code:**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh/gateway'
require 'work/mail/gem'
require 'etc'

def mail_error(e)
  x = AD::Mail.new
  x.from        = "email@email.email"
  x.to          = "email@email.email"
  x.subject     = "Server Loading Error"
  x.body        = e.message
  x.send
end

def scanning_all_servers(server)
  begin
    check = Net::SSH.start(server, @username, :password => @password)
    cmd = "ping -c 1 #{server}"
    check.exec!(cmd)
  rescue => e
    mail_error(e)
    :error
    write_data(server)
  end
end

def server_status(server)
  result = scanning_all_servers(server)

  message_server_online = /1 received, 0% packet loss/i
  message_server_offline = Regexp.union('0 recieved, +1 errors', 'Connection closed')

  result =~ message_server_online  ? :online  :
  result =~ message_server_offline ? :offline : :error
end

def status_message(server, status)
  status == :online  ? "server online: #{server}"  :
  status == :offline ? "[#{Time.now}] SERVER OFFLINE: #{server}" :
                       "[#{Time.now}] Error loading server: #{server}."
end

def write_data(server)
  x = "[#{Time.now}]: Server: #{server} down. Checked by #{@username}. ------------"
  if File.exist?("path/to/log")
     File.open("path/to/log", "a+"){ |s| s.write(x) }
  else
    new_file = File.new("path/to/log", "w")
    new_file.puts(x)
    new_file.close
  end
end

@username = Etc.getlogin
@password = nil

server_list = %w(all of our servers)

server_list.each do |server|
  status = server_status(server)
  puts status_message(server, status)
end
```

**Example of usage:**

> ```
> server online: server
> server online: server
> SERVER OFFLINE: server
> server online: server
> server online: server
> server online: server
> server online: server
> server online: server
> Error loading server: server
> server online: server
> server online: server
> server online: server
> server online: server
> server online: server
> server online: server
> server online: server
> server online: server
> server online: server
> server online: server
> server online: server
> ```

**Example of log:**

> [2015-12-14 06:11:41 -0600]: Server: server down. Checked by user. ------------
>
> [2015-12-14 06:11:45 -0600]: Server: server down. Checked by user. ------------

---

What I would like to know:

- Is there any better ways to write data to files?
- Is there also more readable syntax to use here?

Comment: Round two, +100 rep to best answer

Comment: It would help to specify what else you seek to learn from a review by posting a second bounty.

Comment: @200_Success Well I feel as though the first answer was, and don't get me wrong it was a great answer, very cliche.. It's just boring I guess, I want my code to stand out. Show me gems I can use, show me better syntax, show me different ways I can do things.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll proceed top to bottom.

### `mail_error`

Which would you rather read: `x.body = e.message` or `mail.body = exception.message`?  Don't try to save a few characters on naming — your fellow programmers will like you better.  In particular, `x` has a connotation of being a floating point number, which this isn't.

### `scanning_all_servers` and `server_status`

`Net::SSH#start` does not return a "check".  Rather, it returns a connection.  `conn = Net::SSH.start(…)` would be more appropriate.  Even better, you should call `start` with a block so that the connection gets closed without an explicit call to `close`.

As noted in a review of your previous question, `scanning_all_servers` should be named `scan_server`, since it acts on just one server.  The `:error` symbol isn't doing anything.  Either move it to the end as the implicit return value, or get rid of it.

However, the way that `server_status` and `scanning_all_servers` cooperate is weird.  `scanning_all_servers` plays a part in interpreting the result, but only does a partial job.  Yet, it tries to log that result anyway.  It is also odd that the codepath for writing to the screen is so different from the codepath for writing to the log file.  What you want is **one function whose job is to scan the server and produce a status code**.  Everything else belongs in some other function.

### `status_message` and `write_data`

`status_message` would look slightly tidier using a `case`.

`write_data` has a `File.exist?` test for no reason.  Mode `'a+'` will create the file if it doesn't already exist.  But why does the append case call `write` instead of `puts`, so that there is no newline written?  Also, minor note: `s` looks like a string, so prefer `f` as the variable name for a file.

You seem to be more careful about logging failures than successes, but the successes are just as important, and should also be written to the log file.  Also, all results, whether printed to screen or to the log file, should have timestamps.

### Suggested solution

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh/gateway'
require 'work/mail/gem'
require 'etc'

def mail_error(exception)
  mail = AD::Mail.new
  mail.from     = 'email@example.com'
  mail.to       = 'email@example.com'
  mail.subject  = "Server down"
  mail.body     = exception.message
  mail.send
end

def scan_server(server)
  begin
    Net::SSH.start(server, @username, :password => @password) do |ssh|
      case ssh.exec!("ping -c 1 #{server}")
      when /1 received, 0% packet loss/i
        :online
      else
        :offline
      end
    end
  rescue => e
    :error
  end
end

def status_message(server, status)
  sprintf("[%s]: %s\n", Time.now,
    case status
    when :online
      "server online: #{server}"
    when :offline
      "SERVER OFFLINE: #{server}"
    else
      "Error connecting to server: #{server}"
    end
  )
end

def log(message)
  File.open('path/to/log', 'a+') { |f| f.puts(message) }
end

@username = Etc.getlogin
@password = …

server_list = %w(all of our servers)

server_list.each do |server|
  status = scan_server(server)
  message = status_message(server, status)
  log message
  puts message
end
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is the best answer I'm gonna get this time around, thanks @200_Success

Comment: why would I use `sprintf` instead of just `puts`?

Comment: Better to compose the message once, then use it for both the log file and the screen.

Comment: You could also do string interpolation instead, but in my opinion the expression is too complex for interpolation.

Comment: Awh alright that makes sense, thank you. Also why would you think that logging a bunch of successful connections would be just as important as logging the failed connections?

Comment: In truth, only the up→down and the down→up transitions are noteworthy. However, it's easier just to log everything and analyze it later when you need to investigate a server problem. Also, logging explicit "up" events is helpful when trying to track down intermittent or micro-outages.

Comment: That's true, lol that's why I'm not a sysadmin. Thanks man, defiantly a good answer much appreciated. Also, opening a `File` in `a+` is suppose to automatically create it, I'm well aware of that. For some reason when I do it within any of my programs, it doesn't. Any idea why this could be..?

Comment: Dunno. Maybe you lack write permission for the directory where you want to create the file?

Comment: That would make sense, except it's in my own path.. Idk I'll talk to our sysadmin see what he says, thanks for the awesome answer man.